# History.js and Jquery Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, history.js

Has anyone implemented History.js with the Jquery Pagination plugin? I am having an issue when I navigate away from the pagination page when I go back the pagination starts over and not from the point I found my link.

Answer (score 0):

show me the code, however you can using the Jquery Address:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: Desculpe a demora para responder, então quando muda a páginação, a url do site está alterando  os parâmetros? Exemplo www.site.com/?page=2

Comment: I dont understand spanish sorry

Comment: but after using google translate I can answer your question and no it is not adding a query string at the end of the url when the page changes

Comment: Sorry about the last comment, but then I saw here the jQuery History demo, it works with parameters of anchors:
http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/

As you change the load of your page it adds the anchor with the number of page http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/#2
Maybe you need to set this

Comment: I understand that but where in the pagination script would I enable such that is the issue i am having I am not sure where I need to edit this code to add history

Comment: update this line:
data = data + "<li> <a href = '#' + j +'' onclick = \" History.pushState ({state: null}, 'article, "rtndata + [j]. id +"', 'article' ) return false; \ ">" + rtndata [j]. title + "</ a> </ li>";

Comment: If you do not work, send me the complete code, html and javascript, ok?!